# Derive StartDateTime and EndDateTime from SingleDateTime column with some condition-SQL EXPERTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, join, stored-procedures

For better understanding please find the attached image ([For detailed information please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGwTh.png))

Condition:

1. value_string/Value_Float column field value present i.e Greater than 0, consider as Start_DateTime, next row have same value don’t consider that value just ignore that field. else next row it consists different value consider that one as start_datetime.
2. If value_string/Value_Float column field value  0,consider as End_Time,In every Group if First Value 0 don’t consider.after the start_Datetime arrived 0 considered as End_dateTime
3. If the group does not finish with 0(End_dateTime)  show the field as 'Null'(Example Group C)

**Source Table:**

[image]

**Desired Result**

[image]

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Activity]
( 
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL,     
    [Group] [nvarchar](255) NULL,   
    [Value_String] [float] NULL,    
    [Value_Float] [float] NULL 
)
```

**Insert values**

```
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 11:32.000','A','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 12:13.000','A','1',1)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 17:25.000','A','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 07:32.000','A','12',12)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 11:30.000','A','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 05:02.000','B','15',15)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 06:20.000','B','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 08:16.000','B','5',5)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 19:12.000','B','5',5)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 23:29.000','B','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 11:42.000','C','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 13:20.000','C','4',4)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 16:15.000','C','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 17:52.000','C','4',4)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 23:12.000','C','4',4)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 11:32.000','D','17',17)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 13:47.000','D','15',15)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-23 16:48.000','D','0',0)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 17:32.000','D','24',24)
Insert INTO [Activity] VALUES ( '2021-06-24 19:32.000','D','0',0)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…

```
select min([Datetime]) as startdt, max(next0datetime) as enddt, [Group], Value_String, Value_Float
from
(
select *,  sum(addme) over(partition by [Group] order by [DateTime]) as grpid
from
(
select *,
min(case when Value_String = '0' then [Datetime] end) over(partition by [Group] order by [DateTime] rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
as next0datetime,
case when Value_String <> lag(Value_String) over(partition by [Group] order by [DateTime]) then 1 else 0 end as addme
from dbo.Activity
) as a
) as g
where Value_String <> '0' 
group by [Group], grpid, Value_String, Value_Float
order by [Group], startdt, enddt;
```

Comment: It's working fine and using this Query how to create an Incremental Load Scenario?  if new records inserted it will create a new start time and end time. I want to look up the old start time and end time, if the end time Null then perform the Incremental Load Scenario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr Hloo please help me how to do incremental Load using your Query?